# JPA in Java SE environment: Entity classes loaded without defenition in persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm prepping for Oracle JPAD certification, so I'm playing around a littlebit with Entities in a Java SE environment (at least, that's what I think...). I noticed something on which I'm hoping someone can shed a light on it.

The book Pro JPA2 is what I'm reading. Somewhere at the end of chapter 2, there's an example persistence.xml file with a class defined in it. Ok, so that's the way to go in a Java SE environment, because you don't really have the whole shebang inside a container. But here's the strange thing: I have two Entity classes annotated with @Entity and haven't added any of these to the persistence.xml. But still the're being loaded! I'm gobsmacked. The only thing I can think of now, is that I'm not in an SE environment or it's a new hibernate feature...

Persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="employees" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:." />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="SA" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.shutdown" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
   @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
   public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Date startDate;
    private Long salary;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Employee(String name, Long salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Long getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Long salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [name=" + name + ", salary=" + salary + ", startDate=" + startDate + "]";
    }
}
```

A test:

```
public class TestConnection {

    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private static EntityManager entityManager;
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "employees";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initEntityManager() throws Exception {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        TableStructurePrinter.outputTableStructure(entityManager);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void closeEntityManager() {
        entityManager.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setupDB() throws Exception {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        LoadEmployees.load(entityManager, 4);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void cleanDB() throws Exception {
        entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCountEmployees() {
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select e from Employee e");
        assertEquals(q.getResultList().size(), 4);
    }

}
```

And the output from my TableStructurePrinter (this is a simple select statement from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_COLUMNS):

```
T.TABLE_TYPE         T.TABLE_NAME           C.ORDINAL_POSITION C.COLUMN_NAME                 C.TYPE_NAME        C.COLUMN_SIZE
===================  ===================   =================== ===================   ===================  ===================
TABLE                EMPLOYEE                                1 ID                                 BIGINT                   64
TABLE                EMPLOYEE                                2 NAME                              VARCHAR                  255
TABLE                EMPLOYEE                                3 SALARY                             BIGINT                   64
TABLE                EMPLOYEE                                4 STARTDATE                       TIMESTAMP                   26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate can also autodetect entities, at least in an EE environment but I'd say the same is true for an SE application. AFAIK it will scan the jar containing the persistence.xml file as well as any jars or classes listed there.

A quote from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cfgdepds005.htm:

> **What Persistent Managed Classes Does This Persistence Unit Include?**
>     
> You can specify the persistent managed classes associated with a persistence unit by using one or more of the following:
>
> - <mapping-file> element: specifies one or more object-relational mapping XML files (orm.xml files).
> - <jar-file> element: specifies one or more JAR files that will be searched for classes.
> - <class> element: specifies an explicit list of classes.
> - The annotated managed persistence classes contained in the root of the persistence unit.
>
>   The root of the persistence unit is the JAR file or directory, whose META-INF directory contains the persistence.xml file. To exclude managed persistence classes, add an <exclude-unlisted-classes> element to the persistence unit.

The last part is what is relevant in your case, i.e. the managed classes (entities) are contained in the same jar that contains the persistence.xml and thus are automatically added.

Comment: I think you're right, I didn't even realize a jar file was created at all... But inspecting the jar, I see the entities are not directly in the root, they're in their own respective packages. So now I'm actually having two questions :-)
- Why is the jar created?
- Why are the classes loaded even if they're not directly in the root?

(I'm sorry but I can't get the formatting to work in this reply... I'm looking into it :-))

Comment: @Cesar the "root" is not the root package but the jar file itself (quote from above: `The root of the persistence unit is the JAR file...`) hence the entities are discovered even if they are in their respective packages within that jar. Why the jar is created depends on your build process so you'd have to look into that.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you play with Java SE. Basically in a Java SE environment you MUST specify the managed classes and any other behavior is not portable (check *8.2.1.6.4 List of Managed Classes* below). As arguments I will add excerpts from the JPA 2.0 spec, that explain actually how Hibernate (or EclipseLink as I tested it) works (although not portable) and how you should it:

The set of managed persistence classes that are managed by a persistence unit is defined by using one or more of the following:

**8.2.1.6 mapping-file, jar-file, class, exclude-unlisted-classes**

> - Annotated managed persistence classes contained in the root of the persistence unit (unless the exclude-unlisted-classes element is
>     specified)
> - One or more object/relational mapping XML files
> - One or more jar files that will be searched for classes
> - An explicit list of classes The set of entities managed by the persistence unit is the union of these sources, with the mapping meta-
>     data annotations (or annotation defaults) for any given class being
>     overridden by the XML mapping
>
> The set of entities managed by the persistence unit is the union of
>   these sources[...]

**8.2.1.6.1 Annotated Classes in the Root of the Persistence Unit**

> All classes contained in the root of the persistence unit are searched
>   for annotated managed persistence classes—classes with the Entity,
>   Embeddable, or MappedSuperclass annotation—and any mapping metadata
>   annotations found on these classes will be processed, or they will be
>   mapped using the mapping annotation defaults. If it is not intended
>   that the annotated persistence classes contained in the root of the
>   persistence unit be included in the persistence unit, the
>   exclude-unlisted-classes element must be specified as true.
>   **The exclude-unlisted-classes element is not intended for use in Java SE environments.**

**8.2.1.6.4 List of Managed Classes**

> [...]
>
> A list of all named managed persistence classes must be specified in
>   Java SE environments to insure portability. Portable Java SE
>   applications should not rely on the other mechanisms described here to
>   specify the managed persistence classes of a persistence unit.
>   Persistence providers may require that the set of entity classes and
>   classes that are to be managed must be fully enumerated in each of the
>   persistence.xml files in Java SE environments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The way I see it now is that all of my classes (entities, testclasses and Main) form a whole package that's not designed to be portable, i.e. all of my entities are found.

Comment: Exactly. I know that, because I also test things in a Java SE environment. But that is not portable, although this is the behavior of Hibernate and EclipseLink (!!!the reference implementation!!!) (probably for backward-compatibility reasons). But you said that you prepare for the exam, so you should check there the correct answers, not how hibernate or eclipseLink works.